# Bootstrap Move elements inside navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created navigation bar as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded-bottom">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white font-weight-bold nav-link">Car Shop</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="/cars.html" class="nav-link text-light">Cars</a>
                <a href="/tools.html" class="nav-link text-light">Tools</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Pay</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Right now, all the elements are visually sorted from the left side of the screen. That is fine, except for the Pay button, which I would like to have in the right corner of the navigation bar. I tried doing so by adding

`style="margin-right: 0px;`

to it, but this doesn't seem to be working (it remains at the same place). Can you see my problem?

Comment: What version of BS?

Comment: Placing the button tag just before `</nav>` will work for this one without responsiveness issue as there is no button for collapsing the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `position: absolute;` for your class called **btn** and made it **5px** from the **top** and the **right**. You can adjust as you would like, but the top and right styling only works if you tell the html that the position is absolute.

```css
 .btn {
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light rounded-bottom">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white font-weight-bold nav-link">Car Shop</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="/cars.html" class="nav-link text-light">Cars</a>
                <a href="/tools.html" class="nav-link text-light">Tools</a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Pay</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```